# Two equivalent descriptions of a physical system yielding a non-trivial mathematical formula

Tags: soft-question, mp.mathematical-physics

First I would like to admit that this question may not be entirely appropriate for this site, but I will give it a go none the less.

One often hears stories about how string dualities lead to highly non trivial equations where one side of the equation represents some sort of physical quantity with respect to one theory, and the other side of the equation represents the same physical quantity with respect to the apparatus of the other theory. The most famous of which being the initial mirror symmetry formula derived by physicists which yields a generating function predicting the number of rational curves inside a quintic threefold of a given degree. However, as I am not a physicist, I don't have a single simple example in mind of an analogous phenomenon.

My question is then the following:

What would be an example of some sort of simple physical system, modeled mathematically in two different (but equivalent) ways, that leads to some sort of non-trivial mathematical formula/equality?

Comment: Do Lagrangian, Hamiltonian, and Hamilton-Jacobi formalisms count? What about thermodynamics and statistical physics?

Comment: Let me add Huygens-Fresnel Principle, and Feynman formulation of quantum mechanics (which can be considered as development of this principle. Comparing two descriptions of the motion, it gives a formula for the solution of the Schrodinger equation

Comment: http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath242/kmath242.htm

Answer (score 3):

It's not strictly speaking physics, but I'd say that one of the simplest examples is the [combinatorial proof of Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity#Combinatorial_proof). Quoting Wikipedia:

> Suppose a committee consists of m men and n women. In how many ways can a subcommittee of r members be formed? The answer is $m+n \choose r$.
>
> The answer is also the sum over all possible values of $k$, of the number of subcommittees consisting of $k$ men and $r − k$ women 
>       $\sum_{k=0}^r{m \choose k}{n \choose r-k}$.